# Sencha touch 2 custom list item button tap not fired

Tags: sencha-touch-2, custom-component, mobile-application

I am developing a Hybrid Mobile App over sencha touch 2.
Now I was in a need of a custom component to be specific a custom list item consisting of a button along with.

My view has rendered as i wanted to but the button that is added to the list item is not firing the TAP event as expected. Instead on every tap, the ITEMTAP event is fired which is creating a bit of mess.

Can someone suggest me where to look to make this work ?

Below is the code for the custom component that i created:

```
var listView = {
            xtype : "list",
            id : "desk-list-search-results",
            cls : "desk-list-search-results-cls",
            selectedCls : "",
            defaultType:"desksearchlistitem",
            store : "deskstore",
            flex : 2
        };
```

This is the code for the custom component

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.DeskSearchListItem",{
    extend:"Ext.dataview.component.ListItem",
    requires:["Ext.Button"],
    alias:"widget.desksearchlistitem",
    initialize:function()
    {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    config:{
        layout:{
            type:"hbox",
            align:"left"
        },
        cls:'x-list-item desk-search-list-item',
        title:{
            cls:"desk-list-item",
            flex:0,
            styleHtmlContent:true,
            style:"align:left;"
        },
        image:{
            cls:"circle_image",
            width:"28px",
            height:"28px"
        },
        button:{
            cls:'x-button custom-button custom-font bookdesk-button',
            flex:0,
            text:"Book",
            width:"113px",
            height:"46px",
            hidden:true
        },
        dataMap:{
            getTitle:{
                setHtml:'title'
            }
        }
    },
    applyButton:function(config)
    {
        return Ext.factory(config,Ext.Button,this.getButton());
    },
    updateButton:function(newButton,oldButton)
    {
        if(newButton)
        {
            this.add(newButton);
        }

        if(oldButton)
        {
            this.remove(oldButton);
        }
    },
    applyTitle:function(config)
    {
        return Ext.factory(config,Ext.Component,this.getTitle());
    },
    updateTitle:function(newTitle,oldTitle)
    {
        if(newTitle)
        {
            this.add(newTitle);    
        }
        if(oldTitle)
        {
            this.remove(oldTitle);
        }
    },
    applyImage:function(config)
    {
        return Ext.factory(config,Ext.Component,this.getImage());
    },
    updateImage:function(newImage,oldImage)
    {
        if(newImage)
        {
            this.add(newImage);
        }
        if(oldImage)
        {
            this.remove(oldImage);
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a solution to this,

It can be done into the view using the listeners object.

Here is the code sample for it.

```
listeners:{
                initialize:function()
                {
                    var dataview = this;
                    dataview.on("itemtap",function(list,index,target,record,event){
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });
                    dataview.on("itemswipe",function(list,index,target,record,event){
                        if(event.direction === "right")
                        {
                            var buttonId = target.element.down(".bookdesk-button").id;
                            var buttonEl = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#"+buttonId)[0];
                            if(Ext.isObject(buttonEl))
                            {
                                buttonEl.setZIndex(9999);
                                buttonEl.show({
                                    showAnimation:{
                                        type:"slideIn",
                                        duration:500
                                    }
                                });
                                var listeners = {
                                    tap:function(btn,e,opt)
                                    {
                                        console.log("Button Tapped");
                                    }
                                };

                                buttonEl.setListeners(listeners);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                console.log("This is not a valid element");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

Thanks Anyways.